# AMD OpenCL Version v.s. OpenCL C Version

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, opencl

[I am using ubuntu version 18.04 | amd-gpu Adrenalin 19.7.1]

I was having OpenCL errors with minergate following the default legacy driver installation of AMD for an AMD RX 580:`./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy -y`

The OpenCL version for RX 580 is OpenCL 2.0 according to Wikipedia. Looking at the output of `clinfo`, I see two version numbers. One under `Platform Version`  (OpenCL 2.1) and one under `Device Version` (OpenCL 1.2) which matches that under `Device OpenCL C Version`. I don't know much about OpenCL, but I assume the C version is the version under which OpenCL kernels for the device are compiled. But then what does the platform number mean?

```
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (2841.17)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_gl_sharing
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 2
  Device Name                                     Ellesmere
  Device Vendor                                   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2841.17)
  Driver Version                                  2841.17
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Board Name (AMD)                         Radeon RX 580 Series
  Device Topology (AMD)                           PCI-E, 0b:00.0
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               36
  SIMD per compute unit (AMD)                     4
  SIMD width (AMD)                                16
  SIMD instruction width (AMD)                    1
  Max clock frequency                             1366MHz
  Graphics IP (AMD)                               8.0
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     36
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x1024
  Max work group size                             256
  Preferred work group size (AMD)                 256
  Max work group size (AMD)                       1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              64
  Wavefront width (AMD)                           64
(...)
```